# Как вызвать процедуру в пакете из другой процедуры в другом пакете?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть две процедуры, `name1` и `name2`, которые находяться в разных пакетах. И я хочу вызвать `name2` процедуру в `name1` процедуре.

Как это сделать?

```
PROCEDURE name1 (RC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN RC FOR
      
    END name1;

PROCEDURE name2 (RC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN RC FOR
      SELECT * FROM Person
    END name2;
```

Comment: А что вы ожидаете, или предпологаете, в `OPEN RC FOR` первой процедуры?

Comment: Я удалил из вопроса _Stored procedure_ (хранимка на околоитишном  сленге). Этот термин устарел и больше не употребляется. Есть отдельные функции и процедуры (_standalone_), или пакетированные (_packaged_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Stored procedure(name1 и name2) которые находяться в разных пакетах ...

Пакет - это пространство имён, которое указывается, как и во многих ЯП, через точку (Oracle применяет термин: *Dot Notation*). Внутри пакета, его имя для его собственных идентификаторов опционально и может быть опущено.

Посмотрите на воспроизводимом примере, как это всё работает, и обратите внимание на порядок компиляции пакетов:

```
create table person (id, name) as
    select 1, 'person1' from dual
/
create or replace package pack2 as
    procedure name2 (rc out sys_refcursor);
end pack2; 
/
create or replace package body pack2 as
    procedure name2 (rc out sys_refcursor) is
    begin
        open rc for select * from person;
    end name2;
end pack2; 
/
create or replace package pack1 as
    type persontab is table of person%rowtype;
    procedure name1 (rc out sys_refcursor);
end pack1; 
/
create or replace package body pack1 as
    procedure name1 (rc out sys_refcursor) is
        pt persontab;
    begin 
        pack2.name2 (rc);
        fetch rc bulk collect into pt;
        open rc for select * from table (pt); 
    end name1;
end pack1; 
/
```

Запустите и получите результат:

```
var rc refcursor
execute pack1.name1 (:rc);

        ID NAME   
---------- -------
         1 person1
```